# Compare contents of a variable with several values

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this function called `coolName` that takes an argument `name` and decides whether it's a cool name:

```
function coolName(name) {
  const n = name.toLowerCase();
  return n === 'peter' || n === 'paul' || n === 'mary';
}
```

You could achieve the same using this approach:

```
function coolName(name) {
  return ['peter', 'paul', 'mary'].includes(name.toLowerCase());
}
```

For 3 or more values I need to compare to, I prefer the second approach.

Your thoughts?

Comment: If you expect many calls to occur, you could use a `Set` and call `has`. The set is slower to construct than an array, but `has` is much faster than `includes` on large collections. It also notifies the reader that the collection is not meant to have duplicates. Otherwise the second approach is canonical and readable. Even a very large list would maintain strong readability.

Comment: For such a simple case the only difference is down to a personal preference. Some people use yoda style with the first approach to improve its glanceability and break it into multiple lines ending on `||`. Unless you see a difference in devtools profiler you shouldn't speculate on performance and change the code based on a guess or an idea what will run faster because the actual difference is likely to be within 0.001% of the task's total running time.